# How to use mpi4py in IPython notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, mpi4py

I have an ipcluster running with 8 engines for Ipython notebook. So the following:

```
from IPython import parallel
clients = parallel.Client()
clients.block = True  # use synchronous computations
print clients.ids
```

gives `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. But, I cannot get mpi4py to see these engines:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
print MPI.COMM_WORLD.size
```

gives `1`. I guess, I am missing something basic, so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that it requires some magic. The first line of the cell should be:

```
%%px
from mpi4py import MPI
print MPI.COMM_WORLD.size
```

Comment: What does px mean/stand for?

Comment: @jtlz2 not sure but maybe parallel execute. More info on `%%px` is here: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/parallel/magics.html#px